# How to read a file line-by-line into a vector and then print the vector

Tags: c++, file, file-io, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read in a file, add each line into a vector, and then print the vector. 
 But right now, it will only print the first line. Because of this, I'm assuming that the first line is the only line being added to the vector, but I can't figure out why.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStrs;

    std::ifstream fileIn("example.txt");
    std::string str;
    std::string newLine;
    newLine = str + "\n";

    while (std::getline(fileIn, str)) {
        std::string newLine;
        newLine = str + "\n";
        if (newLine.size() > 0) {
            vecOfStrs.push_back(newLine);
        }
        fileIn.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < vecOfStrs.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << vecOfStrs.at(i) << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the text file, and right now it should print out exactly as it appears here:

```
Barry Sanders
1516 1319 1108 1875 -999
Emmitt Smith
1892 1333 1739 1922 1913 1733 -999
Walter Payton
1999 1827 1725 1677 -999
```

Comment: What did you expect to accomplish by closing the file in the middle of the very first iteration of the loop, and then printing your vector, which now contains the very first line that you've read, and because the file is now closed, the attempt to read the 2nd line from the file obviously now fails? Why did you tell your computer to do exactly this, if your intent was to read the entire file, first, before closing the file? Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer will always do exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do.

Comment: I would strongly suggest adding the `-Wshadow` compiler option, along with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (under gcc/clang) or `/W3` for VS, and don't accept code until it compiles without warning.

Answer (score 0):

There is logic *inside* of your reading loop that really belongs *after* the loop has finished instead:

- You are `close()`'ing the file stream after the 1st line is read, thus breaking the loop after the 1st iteration.
- You are printing the entire `vector` after adding each line to it.

Also, you don't need the `newLine` variables at all.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStrs;
    std::ifstream fileIn("example.txt");
    std::string str;

    while (std::getline(fileIn, str)) {
        if (str.size() > 0) {
            vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
        }
    }

    fileIn.close();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vecOfStrs.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vecOfStrs[i] << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I didnt catch that those were inside the loop.